# Multiple return types of in a method?

Tags: php, return, return-value, return-type

I have a rule class that has a `check($input)` method which returns a boolean `true` if the input is valid or returns a string with the error message when invalid. And because in PHP you can't specify a return type when declaring functions (like in Java for example), you can return whatever.

Is it a best practice to have a method or variable only return/contain one value type? E.g. `boolean`, `string`, or `integer`.

Usually when I'm implementing an interface, only one return type is expected with each of the methods.

Comment: Yes, methods really should stick to returning a single type, you don't want the calling code to have to do a lot of type checking of the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is allright for most of the php functions to have multiple return type. For example [strpos() function](http://www.php.net/strpos)

It will return number if it worked correctly and will return boolean false if it does not work as expected

However , like GordonM said , multiple return type may confuse you when you try to check wheater it worked correctly or not. But in general , multiple return is allright for php functions.